# List commands in a shell's history in the order of their termination times?

Tags: bash, command-history

In a bash shell, `history` will list commands in the order of starting time.

Can I list commands in the order of terminating time?
One possible application is that it will help to retrieve those commands recently terminated but started long time ago, without searching in history.

Comment: It's not possible, you have only HISTCONTROL, HISTFILESIZE, HISTIGNORE, HISTSIZE, HISTTIMEFORMAT. You can have only the starting time ( HISTTIMEFORMAT) and not the finishing time.